# How to sum digits before and after decimal point separately in C?

Tags: c, decimal

I'm supposed to get a decimal number and sum the whole part digits separately and the decimal part separately,

so for example if I get:
1321.0365
the output should be: 7.14

I'm supposed to do that without using arrays.
this is what I tried to do by far, after getting the number from a function, first separating both parts, then multiplying the decimal number by 10, until the number is equal to the int part.
then I tried to sum each of the parts separately, and after i do that, divide the decimal part until the number is equal to the int number.
theoretically it sounds like it should work, but I think I miss something on the way.
this is what I've done so far:

```
double number;
double sumReal=0;
int wholePart;
int sumWhole=0;
int multiply=1;

number=getDecimalNumber();

wholePart=number;
number-=wholePart;

while(number!=(int)number)
 number*=10;

while (number!=0)
{
  sumReal+=(int)number%10;
  number/=10;
}

while (wholePart!=0)
{
  sumWhole+=(int)wholePart%10;
  wholePart/=10;
}

while(sumReal!=(int)sumReal)
  sumReal/10;

number=wholePart+sumReal;
```

somehow most of the parts seem to work, but multiplying the real part by 10 always gets me 0, and when summing the real part and the whole number at the end also gets me 0, which leads me to a 0 output.

Comment: this condition `(number!=(int)number)` will always be true, since you are comparing double with integer, because of limited precision. So you will be stuck in the loop.

Comment: note that due to the bounded precision (number of significant digits) in a `double`, it does not make sense to try dividing and subtracting until you reach zero. You have to pre-define a maximal desired number of decimal places after the decimal point for which you will calculate each digit.

Comment: How does getDecimalNumber work? A double may not be able to actually contain the original input number exactly as given.

Comment: as part of the assignment i was supposed to check each charachter that i get as an input from the user, this is what this function does, it scans each charachter to check if it's a number, and then sums everything to an int (using the ASCII values).

Comment: Use `double modf(double value, double *iptr);` to separate the whole and fractional parts.

Comment: `1321.0365` is typically **not** exactly representable as a `double`.  The closest `double` is more like  `1321.036499999999932697392068803310394287109...`.  So if user has access to the input character string, use [@BLUEPIXY](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27239240/2410359).  Otherwise the problem needs more definition as the sum of _decimal_ digits is problematic with typical binary floating point representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int ch;
    int n1 = 0, n2 = 0;
    while((ch=getchar())!= '.'){
        n1 += ch - '0';
    } 
    while((ch=getchar())!= '\n'){
        n2 += ch - '0';
    }
    printf("%d.%d\n", n1, n2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks! eventually this is how i did it, since the assignment was just to print the output and not to necessarily represent and keep the original number in double.

Comment: this method ignores that fact that the initial value was the returned value from a call to 'getDecimalNumber()'  so getchar() of the value returned from getDecimalNumber() will not work.  This answer makes the assumption that the number is from stdin, which is not listed as part of the basis of the question, so cannot be assumed.

Comment: I do not know well the getDecimalNumber,
Perhaps it is possible to replace getDecimalNumber.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to go this way :

- use the number as string (get a char* pointer on the string so you don't actively use an array)
- split on the decimal point separator
  (you get two char* pointers, one per string)
- iterate on one string char by char (increment the pointer), convert the current char in int and add
- same with second string
- you're done

I strongly suspect it is what your teacher want you to do, more than exotic calculations.

Comment: i wish i could, but i can't use arrays, nor strings :(

Answer (score 0):

```
here is one way to write the algorithm
It may still have bugs that will need the OPs attention


#include <math.h>

// prototypes
double getDoubleNumber(void);
double sumOfDigits( void );


double sumOfDigits()
{
    double doubleNumber = 0.0;

    double wholePart;
    double fractionPart;

    int sumWhole=0;
    int sumFraction = 0;

    double sumParts=0.0;

    // get the original number
    doubleNumber=getDoubleNumber();

    wholePart = trunc(doubleNumber);

    // calc fractional part
    fractionPart = doubleNumber - wholePart;

    // this may need modification due to inexact representation of value
    // move fractionPart to left of decimal point
    while(fractionPart > floor(fractionPart) )
    {
        fractionPart *= 10.0;
    }

    while( trunc(fractionPart) )
    {
        sumFraction += trunc( fmod( fractionPart, 10.0);
        fractionPart /= 10.0;
    }

    // move fractionPart back to right of decimal point
    while( trunc(sumFraction) )
    {
        sumFraction /= 10.0;
    }

    // calc sum of whole part digits
    while ( trunc(wholePart) )
    {
      sumWhole += trunc( fmod( wholePart, 10.0 ) );
      wholePart /= 10.0;
    }



    sumParts = sumWhole+sumFraction;

    return( sumParts );
}  // end function: sumOfDigits
```

Comment: The truncation is redundant because a cast to integer types will always truncate the number. Besides this doesn't work correctly because binary floating-point cannot represent exactly most decimal values, and truncating the number may result in a different int part